# How to detect sound card name?

Tags: windows-7, sound-card

I have a laptop HP Probook 4740S and I can't seem to find which sound card I'm using.
I want to download a sound driver for linux, but don't know which drivers I should download.

In the Device Manager -> I only have Intel(R) Display Audio and ITD High Definition Codec

Comment: The free version of the utility called [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) that can tell you things like this (Windows only).

Comment: With this program:

Sound Cards
 IDT High Definition Audio CODEC
 Intel Display Audio

This is all I get.

Comment: It's probably just some chips on the motherboard. i.e. You don't actaull have a "Sound Card" per se. IDT = Integrated Device Technology (is a company that makes computer chips).

Comment: try http://www.drivernavigator.com/